# Is my sentence 如果我没去上班就一起朋友去玩 grammatially correct?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence-structure, writing-critique

I have written the following sentence

> 如果我没去上班就一起朋友去玩

But, I am not sure if it is grammatically correct or not. Please give me some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

> 如果我没去上班就一起朋友去玩

From my answer to this question [Meaning in context](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/39304/meaning-in-context)

> it is a very common grammar structure
>
> [如果 X 就 Y] = [If X then Y]

[1: 如果] [X: 我没去上班] [2: 就] [Y: 一起朋友去玩]

[1: if ] [X: I don't go to work] [2: then ] [Y: together friend to go play]

The major problem is  "**一起**朋友去玩" (**together** friends to go play)

It should be "**和**朋友一起去玩" (go to play **with** friends together)

[和 + (noun) 一起] = [with + (noun)  together] is also a common grammar structure. And you can drop "一起" and write: "**如果我没去上班就和朋友**(*一起*)**去玩**" because it is strongly implied with the present of 和

Answer (score 0):

如果我没去上班，就和朋友一起去玩。
If I don't go to work, I'd hang out with friends.

Comment: Is this sentence correct

Comment: If that's what you mean in English, then the Chinese translation is correct.