# Is my sentence 如果没时间的话就告诉我 grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, word, sentence-structure, writing-critique

I am not sure that my sentence:

> 如果没时间的话就告诉我

is grammatically  correct or not. So please guide me, have I used the right words?

Answer (score 2):

> 如果没时间的话就告诉我

Your sentence is grammatically correct and it is a very common grammar structure

[如果 X 就 Y] = [If X then Y]

[1: 如果] [X: 没时间的话] [2:就] [Y:告诉我]

[1: if ] [X: suppose you have no time] [2: then ] [Y: tell me]

Notice 1: The subject 'you' is omitted in Chinese sentence and it is a very common practice, you can drop the subject as long as it is clearly understood in the context.

Notice 2: Since [如果 ~ 就] is a common structure, you can omit 如果 and write "(*如果*)**没时间的话就告诉我**". The sentence would still be correct because "如果" is strongly implied with the present of "就"

Notice 3:"的话" in "没时间的话" means "suppose" . And you can drop it too. The result is a blunter sentence "如果没时间就告诉我" (if you have no time, then tell me) sounds more like a command  than a suggestion or request

Answer (score 0):

If you meant: "If you don't have time, just let me know" than this sentence is correct and is in a very native speaker fashion. You can even drop the 如果 to make it more native.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct.
A more colloquial way may be 如果没**空**的话就告诉我